# Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): No such module 'shared_preferences_ios' - Flutter

Tags: xcode, flutter, dart, notifications, awesome-notifications

## Notes

- Recently updated to Xcode Version 14.2 (14C18)
- Flutter 3.7.0 • channel stable

## Problem

When running my flutter app for ios, I get this error:

```
Xcode build done.                                           86.8s
Failed to build iOS app
Could not build the precompiled application for the device.
Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): No such module 'shared_preferences_ios'
/Users/tomasward/Desktop/fredi_new/ios/Runner/AppDelegate.swift:3:7
```

Which is derived from this piece of code in `AppDelegate.swift`:

```
import UIKit
import Flutter
import awesome_notifications
import shared_preferences_ios //error here

@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
  override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
  ) -> Bool {
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
      
      if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
           UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self as? UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate
          }
         
       application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
      

            SwiftAwesomeNotificationsPlugin.setPluginRegistrantCallback { registry in
                SwiftAwesomeNotificationsPlugin.register(
                  with: registry.registrar(forPlugin: "io.flutter.plugins.awesomenotifications.AwesomeNotificationsPlugin")!)
                FLTSharedPreferencesPlugin.register(
                  with: registry.registrar(forPlugin: "io.flutter.plugins.sharedpreferences.SharedPreferencesPlugin")!)
            }
    return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
  }
}
```

This code is boilerplate for the `awesome_notifications` plugin setup for ios. [See here](https://pub.dev/packages/awesome_notifications#-configuring-ios)

## I Have tried a million solutions

- Deleting ios build and running `flutter create .`
- Running `pod install` a million times, deleting podfile, etc.

No solution seems to be consistent. I am looking for a general solution from people working on `Flutter` projects, not native ios projects.

Also it would be great if someone who worked with `awesome_notifications` could give me some insight

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kudos to the answer on [this link](https://github.com/rafaelsetragni/awesome_notifications/issues/708):

> This is issue created by shared_preferences v2.0.16. Long story short - package/module shared_preferences_ios was renamed to shared_preferences_foundation. Fastest way to work around this is to downgrade shared_preferences to 2.0.15.

```
shared_preferences: ^2.0.15 # Before
shared_preferences: 2.0.15 # After
```

You will then see this log when you run `flutter pub get`:

```
< shared_preferences 2.0.15 (was 2.0.17) (2.0.17 available)
+ shared_preferences_ios 2.1.1
+ shared_preferences_macos 2.0.5
```

Also, be careful with spelling mistakes as `shared_prefrences_ios` (wrong) is very similar to `shared_preferences_ios` (correct).

Comment: Should we still use shared_preferences_ios? as it is deprecated? "SharedPreferencesIOS.registerWith()" how to initiated register with with shared_preferences_foundation lib?

Answer (score 5):

For Latest/Current Version do this below

replace `shared_preferences_ios` with `shared_preferences_foundation`

and `FLTSharedPreferencesPlugin` with `SharedPreferencesPlugin`

as these are the latest native bindings of flutter internal [See PR](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/pull/6940).

`AppDelegate.swift` contents with new updated solution

```
import UIKit
import Flutter
import awesome_notifications
import shared_preferences_foundation //replace this here

@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
  override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
  ) -> Bool {
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)

      if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
          UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self as? UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate
      }

      application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

            SwiftAwesomeNotificationsPlugin.setPluginRegistrantCallback { registry in
                SwiftAwesomeNotificationsPlugin.register(
                  with: registry.registrar(forPlugin: "io.flutter.plugins.awesomenotifications.AwesomeNotificationsPlugin")!)
                SharedPreferencesPlugin.register( // replace here
                  with: registry.registrar(forPlugin: "io.flutter.plugins.sharedpreferences.SharedPreferencesPlugin")!)
            }
    return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
  }
}
```

Comment: this is the good approach

Answer (score 1):

As you're probably already aware by now, `shared_preferences_ios` went away with `shared_preferences` version 2.0.16. So the fact you're seeing that means something didn't get updated correctly along the way.

What version of Flutter were you on previously?

FWIW my `AppDelegate.swift` looks quite different, and notably does not include imports for specific plugins:

```swift
import UIKit
import Flutter

@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
  override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
  ) -> Bool {
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
    return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
  }
}
```

On the other hand, I'm not using `awesome_notifications`. Is it possible the setup for it has changed since you first integrated, and the `AppDelegate.swift` modifications are no longer relevant? And, you're on the latest version of `awesome_notifications`?

Sorry I don't have an immediate and direct answer, but I hope this helps.

Comment: thanks @chuck, although you did not provide me with the exact answer, your first part of the response was key. I did not know that the shared_preferences_ios was deprecated, and with that, I could dig deeper.

Comment: Do we still have to use "SharedPreferencesIOS.registerWith()" or how to register now when new lib (foundation) does not have that method?